# Symfony 2: cannot add a User-Entity to a Item-Entity as it's owner

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to **add a User** to the **Item** as it's **owner**

- **manually** in the Controller by `$item->setOwner($this->getUser());`
- in a **ManyToOne**-relation.

Everything defined in the FormType gets saved as it should but the `owner_id` is `NULL`. I don't get any error-message.

Any ideas? Code below.

Thanks in advance!

```
# src/myBundle/Controller/myController.php
class myController extends Controller {
    public function myAction(Request $request) {
        $item = new Item();
        $item->setOwner($this->getUser());

        // print_r($this->getUser());  <- prints a valid user

        $form = $this->createForm(new ItemFormType(), $item);
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
                $em->persist($item); // saves everything but the owner
                $em->flush();
            }
        }

        return $this->render('myBundle:path/to:template.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form
        )
    }
}
```

-

```
# src/myBundle/Form/ItemFormType.php
class ItemFormType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {            
        $builder->add(...);
        // ...
    }
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'myBundle\Entity\Item'
    ));
}

public function getName() {
    return 'myItemForm';
}
```

-

```
# src/myBundle/Entity/Item.php
class Item {
     // ...
     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="myBundle\Entity\User")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
    protected $owner;

     // ...
     // Getter & Setter
     // ...     
}
```

-

```
# src/myBundle/Entity/User.php
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might have to show your full ItemType form class. Does it persist correctly if you skip the form binding and validation (or set the user explicitly after form binding)?

Comment: @Ryan: Problem solved. I named two columns of the same table "owner", the second overwrote the first with an empty value. Didn't notice due copy & paste. Well, that's a shame. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Unfortunately I didn't change the `column-name` of `$deletedBy` after copy & pasting `$owner`. Result: `$deletedBy` overwrote `$owner` with an empty value.

```
# src/myBundle/Entity/Item.php
class Item {
     // ...
     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="myBundle\Entity\User")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
    protected $owner;

    // many more

    /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="myBundle\Entity\User")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id") <- "owner_id"
      */
    protected $deletedBy;

    // ...
    // Getter & Setter
    // ...     
}
```